# App doesn't open correctly when I open a notification

Tags: bug, android-app

I have Samsung A5, SM-A500H. Android version 5.0.2. Latest version of SE android app on Google Play Store.

If I ask a question, you answer, I receive a notification on my phone that you answered, I click on the notification, I see this

> [image]

So it doesn't load correctly, I have to go back and click on the notification icon from within the app for it to open correctly.

Comment: I also have this exact problem. It sometimes spends a while looking like it's loading, but it always requires me to close and reopen the notifications to actually load it.